# How can I query from lowdb that will return result within a given range?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using Nodejs for backend. For the database I am using [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) which is a small local database for small projects (powered by Lodash API). What I want is a limit query from lowdb.

For example, I had users in the db say having id from 1-200. Now I want a query that will return me user from say 50-100. How can I do that?

Comment: Just wondering whether my answer was helpful ? If yes, please could you accept it?

Comment: I am also wondering if @notionquest's answer was helpful, noting Rabby that you signed in two hours ago today. Please consider clicking the tick mark adjacent to the answer if this was helpful to you. This is how we thank people for their time on this site.

Comment: I already tried with "slice" before the answer was given. So that's why the answer is not helpful for me. Thank you to notify me about that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **"slice"** to get the records from 50 to 100.

slice(50, 101)

**Example to get the first 2 records:-**

Please note that I have given '3' because it excludes '2' if you give '2'. For your requirement, you have to give (50, 101).

```
console.log(db.get('posts')
          .slice(1, 3)
          .value());
```